# How to make a Service/Factory with $http in AngularJS 1.5+? (ES6)

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-service, angularjs-components

I'm using this [boilerplate](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter) for angular.js 1.5, I haven't work with the new angularjs sintax and am lost of how to use and inject `$http` for http request.

In the past I would use an old angularjs service (`MyService`) and inside it inject $http then I would call in my controller the `MyService.getData()`, but with this new syntax I'm lost how to create a service and inject inside it $http and then use that service in a component.

This is how the module file questions.js looks like:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import questionsComponent from './questions.component';

    let questionsModule = angular.module('questions', [
      uiRouter
    ])
    .component('questions', questionsComponent)
    .name;

    export default questionsModule;
```

The `questions.component.js`:

```
import template from './questions.html';
import controller from './questions.controller';
import './questions.scss';
let questionsComponent = {
  bindings: {},
  template,
  controller
};

export default questionsComponent;
```

And finally the `questions.controller.js`:

```
class QuestionsController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'questions';
  }

  $onInit() {
    console.log("$onInit")
  }

  $onDestroy() {
    console.log("$onDestroy")
  }
}

export default QuestionsController;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally got it working:

```
import angular from 'angular';

class HttpService {
  static $inject = ['$http','$q']

  constructor($http, $q) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  getResults() {
    console.log("getResults()")
    //return this.$http.get('/foo/bar/');
    this.$http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshopbattles/comments/6kl24d/psbattle_bat_carrying_baby.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("response", response)
      });
  }
}


export default HttpService;
```

In the controller:

```
class QuestionsController {
  static $inject = ['HttpService']

  constructor(HttpService) {
    this.name = 'questions';
    this.service = HttpService;
  }

  $onInit() {
    console.log("$onInit")
    this.service.getResults();
  }

  $onDestroy() {
    console.log("$onDestroy")
  }
}
export default QuestionsController;
```

In the module:

```
let questionsModule = angular.module('questions', [
  uiRouter,
  User
])
  .service('HttpService', HttpService)
  .component('questions', questionsComponent)
  .name;

export default questionsModule;
```